# How to create an automatic popup video when a page loads in a svelte file?

Tags: html, svelte, sveltekit

I'm building a portfolio and planning to have a video there when a user opens the site. How can I add an iframe to automatically open when the page loads? I'm using sveltekit for creating pages on the site.

Comment: The functionality you are askign for is provided not by Svelte, but any UI framework you are using. Here is an example for Bootstrap modal: https://sveltestrap.js.org/?path=/story/components--modals Thus, first you need to decide what UI framework your websites uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try

```
document.onload = {
  let iframe = "<iframe> ... </iframe>";
  let frameWrap = document.querySelector('.frame-wrapper');
  frameWrap.innerHTML = iframe
  // or: frameWrap.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', iframe)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a bootstrap modal window to display it
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

for example

```
 <script>$(document).ready (function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    
    
    });
    </script>
    
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    
    
    
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    
     <video width="400">
  <source src="#" type="video/mp4">

    </div></video>
    
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" />
    <label2 for="cb1" data-dismiss="modal">Close</label2>
    
    
    
    
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```